# Kivy MD : line_color_normal Property Not Working

Tags: python, input, dialog, kivymd

I have made a dialog box in kivy MD and I have put an MDTextField inside it. Then, I tried to change the `line_color_normal` property in order to make the text field look cooler, but that didn't work.

```
class MyProgramApp(MDApp):
    def pop_dialog(self, *args):
        input_box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None,
                             height=100)
        self.text = MDTextField(hint_text='Name',
                            size_hint_x=0.9, color_mode='custom', line_color_normal=(1, 0, 0, 1))
        input_box.add_widget(self.text)
        self.dialog = MDDialog(title='Create', type='custom',
                         content_cls=input_box)
        self.dialog.open()
```

I have looked at the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/text-field/index.html#:%7E:text=MDTextField%3A%0A%20%20%20%20hint_text%3A%20%22Line%20color%20normal%22%0A%20%20%20%20line_color_normal%3A%20app.theme_cls.accent_color) but it didn't help.

Comment: First set `color_mode` to 'custom'.

Comment: I actually did that and it throws an error : ``ValueError: None is not allowed for MDTextField._current_line_color``

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).